# Changing the language using payload in Node-RED for Watson language translator

Tags: language-translation

The Node-RED Info tab for Watson IoT Language Translator states: Source and destination language parameters can be configured through the editor panel or set dynamically using the language codes in the following properties, msg.srclang and msg.destlang. Please see the documentation linked below for the currently supported source and destination language codes.

However the linked documentation contains no such help on what codes to use - and a google web search reveals nothing. Anyone have any clues ?

Comment: You're right, that link appears to be broken.  I'll report it to the Watson documentation team and see if I can find any further info for you.

Answer (score 1):

That link should point to this documentation page: 
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/language-translator/

See below the translations currently supported, use the 2 digit iso code for the srclang and destlang.

Today, the basic Language Translator service offers three domain-specific translation models:

News - targeted at news articles and transcripts, it translates English to and from Arabic, Brazilian Portuguese, French, German, Italian, Japanese, or Spanish. It also translates Spanish to and from French.

Conversational - targeted at conversational colloquialisms, it translates English to and from Arabic, Brazilian Portuguese, French, Italian, or Spanish.

Patents - targeted at technical and legal terminology, it translates Brazilian Portuguese, Chinese, or Spanish to English.

Comment: Its actually a 2 or 5 character IETF language tag, which are related to the ISO codes.